# How to get rid of line in drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W88vV.png)

Hi I have a problem where my black horizontal lines between menu items is also appearing in the dropdown menu which looks messy. An example is in the above image. Any ideas how I might remove it/exclude the drop down menu from my code which is below

```
.site-nav li {
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
margin: 0px 0;
}
.site-nav li:first-child {
border-left: none;
}
.site-nav li > a {
line-height: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Francis

Comment: Could you post your html structure as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `.site-nav li {` to `.site-nav > ul > li {`
(Or: `.site-nav > li {` if your site-nav class is on the ul element.)

You can also add this to your css instead:
`site-nav li li {
  border-left: none;
}`

Another option is to add this class to the elements that you wish to remove the borders on:
`.no-border {
  border-left: none;
}`

Comment: Quickest answer and solution ever. Massive oversight on my part. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If `.site-nav` is your class for your `ul` element, try this.

```
.site-nav > li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0px 0;
}
```

Or, if `.site-nav` is not defined class for `ul` element, try this.

```
.site-nav ul > li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the border from your nested li the same way you've removed it from the `first-child`

```
.site-nav > [dropdown element name] li {
border-left: none;
}
```